# SetAttribute for indicized variables?

Tags: attributes

Is there a way to `SetAttributes` to a function defined like this:

```
fun[t_][x_,y_]
```

Something like `SetAttrubutes[fun[t_],Listable]`?

Comment: Only symbols, not indexed symbols can have attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make `fun[t]` return a pure `Function` and make that one `Listable` like this:

```
fun[t_] := Function[{x, y}, DoSomething[x, y, t], Listable];
```

Here is a simple example:

```
X = Range[5];
Y = Range[5];
fun[t][X, Y]
```

> {DoSomething[1, 1, t], DoSomething[2, 2, t], DoSomething[3, 3, t], DoSomething[4, 4, t], DoSomething[5, 5, t]}

However, I believe to remember that there was some performance issue with pure functions with `Listable` attribute (at least in some version of Mathematica). It's been a while ago. Maybe this issue has been fixed already.